# Homomorphic Images of $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I had a question that's stumping me from an exam review for my abstract algebra class. The problem is as follows:

Find all of the homomorphic images of $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$.

From what I recall, this should be pretty basic, but it's been a while since I did something like this. I'm not sure where to even start. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The image of a cyclic group is cyclic, and for finite groups, the order of the image divides the order of the original group. (and I hope the question is just asking up to isomorphism!)

Comment: So in other words, of the subgroups of order 1, 2, 3, or 6, those that are cyclic will be homomorphic images?

Comment: @M.Vinay So how would you tell which ones are?

Comment: @A.S.Hopkins In this case, that happens to be correct, but not in general. See my comment on one of the answers.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in this Question that distinguishes groups from rings.

Answer (score 4):

By the first isomorphism theorem, any homomorphic image of a group is isomorphic to a quotient by the kernel. So, you should find all normal subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ (there will be 4 of them), and the quotients will classify all possible homomorphic images.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is in some sense more elementary than lisyarus's answer, but this does not mean the first isomorphism theorem is not an important tool in your algebraic arsenal.

For any homomorphism $h$ from $\mathbb{Z}_6$ onto a group a $G$ with identity $e$, it must be that $(h(1))^6 = e$. More importantly, because $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is cyclic, its image under $h$ will also be cyclic and entirely determined by the order of $h(1)$, its generator.

How many possibilities do we have for the order of $h(1)$? The only requirement is that the order divide $6$, for otherwise we would not have $(h(1))^6=e$. Since $6$ has four divisors, there are four homomorphic images of $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

- Divisor $1$: $\mathbb{Z}_{1} = \{e\}$, the group with a single element.
- Divisor $2$: $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$; $h$ is the remainder modulo $2$.
- Divisor $3$: $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$; $h$ is the remainder modulo $3$.
- Divisor $6$: $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$; $h$ is the 'identity'.

Comment: Since you (A.S. Hopkins) are reviewing basic group theory, I'd like to point out that this example may be highly misleading. Here, the homomorphic images are all (isomorphic to) subgroups of the domain group $\mathbb Z_6$. This need not be true in general. They are actually *quotients* of $\mathbb Z_6$ (as you can understand from the first isomorphism theorem, also mentioned in lisyarus's answer). Quotient groups need not be isomorphic to subgroups. But here, there are no other (non-isomorphic) groups of these orders (1, 2, 3), so the quotients are forced to be isomorphic to subgroups.

Comment: @M.Vinay Yeah, this reasoning should be taken as characteristic of cyclic groups, not groups in general.

Comment: Your reasoning works in the general case too (except that a generating set may have more than one element, and so the image group will be determined by the images of all of these, and you have to check for consistency [well-definedness]). It's only the final "answer" that is misleading in its simplicity [a (very) naïve conjecture may be made, that the set of all homomorphic images is the set of all subgroups].